# How to make the delete button work in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, nodes

I am not sure what is wrong with my code. I am new to express.
[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSafE.png)  [list.ejs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfXLJ.png)

I thought I misspelled a variable, but I am unsure what I did wrong. I am making a todo list project using express and node.js and I need to have a remove task option.

My app.js code is:

```js
app.post('/removetask', (req, res) => {
  const task = req.body.task;
  task.splice(task.indexOf(task), 1);
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

and my list.js used in the browser is:

```html
<form action="/" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="newItem" >
  <button type="submit">Add</button>
  <button formaction="/removetask" type="submit" id="top">Remove</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of an image.

Comment: I did just now.

Comment: You're overwriting whateer `task` is with the one you're pulling from `req.body`. Presumably you have a master list called `tasks` with an `s` at the end, and you meant to splice the posted task out of _that_, and you typoed it twice. Because `a.splice(a.indexOf(a),1)`, no matter what `a` is, makes no sense. Not even if you have code where `a` is an array that contains itself (because at that point you're doing some _craaaazy_ stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary issue is that you're trying to use the splice method on a variable named `task`, which seems to be a `string` (as it's coming from the form's input field).

But you need to maintain an array of `tasks` to add and remove task

```
const tasks = [] //array of tasks

app.post('/removetask', (req, res) => {
  const taskIndex = tasks.indexOf(req.body.task);
  if (taskIndex !== -1) {
    tasks.splice(taskIndex, 1);
  }
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

With these changes, you will maintain an array of tasks on the server-side and correctly add or remove tasks.
The splice method is used to modify the tasks array.